# Backup to an encrypted blob on a friend's PC

Tags: backup

Some time ago I found a piece of software that allowed me to install it on a friend's PC, have the friend allocate a bunch of space to it, and store my backups on that friend's PC. The backups were encrypted before leaving my PC, so that all that's visible on the remote PC is a huge encrypted file.

No matter how hard I try to find it now, all that comes up are products for cloud backup, or rsync GUIs.

Does anyone know a program that does this? Please help me find it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com) can do encrypted peer to peer backups.

Comment: Seconded - it does exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes, I use CrashPlan for this.